# Getting Error to delete keys by pattern in redis

Tags: redis

I am trying  to execute query `redis-cli --raw keys "$xx" | xargs redis-cli del` but getting error.

> ERR wrong number of arguments for 'del' command

Comment: Hi, select needed key in https://fastoredis.com and press del

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead, to wrap the key in quotes:

`redis-cli keys "pattern" | xargs -I% redis-cli del "%"`

This takes each key as a variable, `%`, and passes it to `redis-cli del` but wraps it in double quotes in case it contains non-alphanumeric characters (like period,colon,etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Check what `redis-cli --raw keys "$xx"` is returning: you'll see that error when you call `redis-cli del` without any arguments.